# Notify PropertyChanged on ClearChanges/Refresh

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, telerik-open-access

I want my UI that is basically purely built on data-binding to refresh when I call `ClearChange()` or `Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteChangesFromStore,obj)`. However it looks like the backing fields are used directly by DataAccess instead of the properties they are backing as the setters are not accessed yet the object's properties do indeed get reverted back.

Is there a way to tell DataAccess to use the properties instead so `PropertyChanged` is called within the setter?

Possibly any other solution? Nothing efficient comes to my mind

Comment: Here you could subscribe to the context tracking mechanism and provide your own logic to handle this scenario.
http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/feature-reference/api/context-api/feature-ref-api-context-api-tracking-context-changes

Comment: Sadly I don't see a way how to handle the ClearChanges being called, unless I missed something?

Comment: @DamyanBogoev any idea?